Downvoting on closed questions, is alright?
I got two down votes this for my question that was closed 4 months back, I have also marked it for deletion. then why downvoting?

This answer on meta.SO explains the reasoning. The basic idea is that the question may also get up votes, votes to reopen, edits, and so on that might salvage it. It takes sufficient delete votes to establish the question as unsavable and end the process.
If you'd like, I'll delete the question for you. It just didn't get enough delete votes.

yes, please delete it. In future, you may consider deleting a question if it received only one delete vote from the same person who asked the question.

@vi.su. it is automatic if it has no answers, but if there are answers, then it's up to the community to decide if they are worth keeping or not.

@vi.su. though it may be a bit controversial in some circles the basic idea here is that things posted on a SE site belong to that SE's community. A delete vote from a question without answers or activity usually just means someone thought twice about their contribution, but once a question has answers or comments deleting it would destroy the contribution of other individuals as well so the choice to delete should belong to the community at that point. Very often one can learn a lot even from closed questions. Don't worry about rep, just keep participating and the rep will handle itself.
